# Where put the code of MainActivity to another Class or Content Page in Xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using Xamarin Forms.
In my application I have to implement the GeoFence.
I got a sample geofence application in

Xamarin Android:https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/google-services/Location/Geofencing/

But this codes writen inside the MainActivity Page,so I want to use that code inside my Xamarin Forms.How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In your solution there are three projects, one of them is .Android project where you have the MainActivity. You will probably be able to place the code there, if not then you'll likely need to implement dependency service (or switch your project to shared project as it is much simpler to do that there, then you can do everything in your main project just using the conditional compiling).

Answer (score 0):

Same situation i used switch/case

```
  `switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
        {              

            case Device.UWP:
               //you code here
            break;

           case Device.Android:
              //you code here
           break;
             case Device.IOS:
             //you code here
           break;
       }`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the MainActivity Page in xxxx.Droid folder.

If you use Xamarin forms. You could use this plugin nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Geofence to create a cross-platform GeoFence.

Here is sample github.com/domaven/xamarin-plugins/tree/master/Samples/Geofence

Comment: Do you have any updates? If the reply help to you, please mark the reply as answer.